# Does my Gigabyte H61M-DS2 DVI (Intel H61 Chipset) motherboard support NVMe SSD drives?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, nvme

I am a newbie here (so please take it easy on me!)

Can anyone help with my questions - Does my Gigabyte H61M-DS2 DVI (Intel H61 Chipset) motherboard support NVMe SSD drives?

Comment: Do you want to use it as a boot drive or storage? I *think* its too old to use it as a boot drive - and since it won't have a NVMe slot, you'd need an adaptor anyway....

Comment: The motherboard would require a PCIe card that supports NVMe.  The motherboard, according to its specifications, obviously does not support NVMe.  If you can or can't boot from the drive, off storage installed in that appropriate adapter card, would be a different question and would require the specifications of that specific adapter card.  NVMe drives typically require you to use UEFI, which of course the motherboard supports, and the motherboard certainly would supports PCIe SSDs.

Answer (score 2):

'Yes' and no.

You don't have 'native' NVMe slots - as Harry's answer has alluded to but that doesn't mean you can't plug in and use an NVMe drive on a PC without those sockets, or with insufficient PCIe sockets.

In your case - if you have spare PCIe sockets, you can use an adaptor like the one below to plug in an NVMe drive into an X4 (or better) PCIe socket. I would suggest one that's not sharing lanes with your video card. These are labeled as M.2 NVMe to PCIe x16 adaptors and I have one here with the x8 and x16 pins snapped off. The adaptors are under a fiver from say AliExpress

[image]

As for the 'no' You can't boot off it - the PCs of the era probably didn't 'know' fast PCIe storage existed, and bios wouldn't be able to initiate it. It didn't even turn up on the system I tested it on in the bios as a drive. Your bootloader would likely need to be on a SATA drive of some sort.

You can however use it as a fast storage drive on a PC of that era - I tested mine on windows 10 on a roughly contemporary machine with no real issues. In theory, while it's a whole another question - if you could keep the bootloader on another drive you *could* boot an OS that's hosted on it. Another alternative (and that's something I came across

Comment: The author **might** be able to boot off a straight PCIe SSD.  It honestly would be a flip of a coin due to the old chipset.

Comment: Well, that would be a bonus. Allegedly you can also use DUET/REFIND for it or other tools but that's a little out of my comfort zone. Or hack the bios - and I'm not brave enough to try that :D. In any case, its the hardware OP needs to start.

Comment: Not likely possible - this motherboard only has one x16 PCI Express slot, probably used for the graphic adapter. The other PCI Express slots are only x1, so useless for NVMe.

Answer (score 0):

The
[GA-H61M-DS2 DVI (rev. 1.0)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-DS2-DVI-rev-10/sp#sp)
has in its specification the following:

```
Storage Interface  
Chipset:
    1. 4 x SATA 3Gb/s connectors supporting up to 4 SATA 3Gb/s devices
```

So the answer is negative : Your motherboard only supports SATA SSD,
not NVMe.

Comment: Don't downvote correct answers, please.

Answer (score 0):

All very helpful comments.  Thank you everyone.

Sadly the consensus seems to be that I cannot use it as my boot and data drive which is what I was hoping for.

I may need to consider installing a sata SSD instead.

Have a great day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I using H61 too, and saw Thai Youtuber showing how to add NVMe driver to bios. It's call MOD Bios.

That working for oldest chipset is H61.

Here's [Youtube a link Thai Youtuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDryPUJwNyE)[1]
[Credit](https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/howto-get-full-nvme-support-for-all-systems-with-an-ami-uefi-bios/30901)[2]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126540)

Comment: This's site guide to Mod Bios add NVMe to AMI bios

https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/howto-get-full-nvme-support-for-all-systems-with-an-ami-uefi-bios/30901